# How to set a principal class for bundle

Tags: swift, xcode

How to set principal class for a bundle? The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1409048-principalclass) does not mention the path string format.

Answer (score 0):

In your target's `Info.plist` file add `Principal Class` key with value type set to string:

[image]

Set key's value to `"{{YOUR TARGET NAME}}.{{YOUR CLASS NAME}}"` (e.g. `"TargetName.ClassName"`)

To prevent hardcoding target name, it's good idea to use `$(TARGET_NAME)` variable.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1409048-principalclass) does not mention the path string format. I thought someone might find this useful.